# How to accept . in url regex and still exclude the format

Tags: regex, django-rest-framework, routes

I'm trying to create a regex pattern on the `lookup_value_regex` on a `django-rest-framework` api that accepts urls such as:

```
/alice_test
/alice_test.json
/alice.test
/alice.test.json
/alice_test.so@gmail.com
/alice_test.so@gmail.com.json
```

PS: The `username` after the `/` can contain a _.@- at any point.

and correctly identifies when to use the json format to return a response. Currently I've tried modifying the `lookup_value_regex` in my Viewset like so.

```py
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    lookup_value_regex = r'(?<=/)[\w.@+-]+?(?=\.json|\.csv|\.xml|$)'
```

This implementation when tested with my example paths above, returns the following lookup values

```
/alice_test # alice_test -- OK
/alice_test.json # alice_test.json -- NOT OK
/alice.test # alive.test -- OK
/alice.test.json # alice.test.json -- NOT OK
/alice_test.so@gmail.com # alice_test.so@gmail.com -- OK
/alice_test.so@gmail.com.json # alice_test.so@gmail.com.json -- NOT OK
```

How do i make the `lookup_value_regex` work and correctly pick out when it should utilize the format for response ?

Ultimately I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the regex `[^/.]+` but in this case it should accept a `.` and be able to still distinguish between the username and format. Such that grouping the regex like so: `(?P<username>[^/.]+)` then adding `\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)` to the regex making it `(?P<username>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)` would correctly pick the `username` and `format`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regex

```
(\/\w*){2}\/\w*[._]?\w*(\@)?\w*(\.\w*)*
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/VYvHME/1)

Comment: This seems to not work.... sorry my question probably had misleading examples. Updated it to show what type of input / string the regex would more than likely be working on

Answer (score 0):

I've made this one :

```
(?:\/([\w-\.]+)@?(?:[\w-\.]+)?.((?:json)|(?:xml)|(?:csv)))$|(?:\/([\w-\.]+)@?(?:[\w-\.]+)?)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Mo8VLE/1)

If you've got something in group 3 it's the user and it means that you didn't match any format. If you've got something in group 1 it's the user and group 2 it's the format.